# ASP.NET MVC2 built in account tools

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am attempting to create a classified site, whereby users can register to my site and then add a classified listing. I would like to use AccountController - my basic conundrum is when I add an advert I need it to be linked to a specific user.

E.G. User SSMith has created a new listing (View all listings by SSmith)

Is the built in AccountController capable of doing this? E.g. If I have a Listings table within my database how can I link the user account to that listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the relevant actions on your Listings controller require a user to be authenticated so that you know who they are when they save a listing.  Adding the [Authorize] attribute to the relevant actions is a simple place to start.

For a simple example look at this section of the Nerd Dinner tutorial http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part9.htm.

Comment: Hello Chris, many thanks for your answer, I have been using the MvcMusicStore tutorial. I like the Authorize attribute and grasp that, what I am failing to see is how I can link a Classified Listing (in my database listing table) to a user logged in via the AccountController?

Comment: Chris great steer regarding Nerd Dinners - it follows the structure of a classified ads a lot closer. I was able to view the NerdDinners DB and find out how they had connect it to the DB. Top Man!